# Entering parentheses in string values

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to enter a value for a string variable which contains parentheses.

```
ValueString = "'("&data1&"')"
```

For this example, Data1 has a value of 6 ( I confirmed that the variable has a value prior to this line of code)

I want the value of ValueString to be (6)

When run, I get "expected end of statement"  with the  `&"')"` highlighted.

I have tried many variations of this syntax, with the same result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Public Sub Import2(FileName As Variant)
Dim wb As Object, ws As Object
Dim xl As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("excel.Application")
Dim qs As String
Dim ValueString As String

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        Set ws = wb.worksheets("For Export")
        data1 = ws.cells(2, 1)
        Data2 = ws.cells(2, 2)
        Data3 = ws.cells(2, 3)
  ValueString = "(" & data1 & ")"
qs = "INSERT INTO MAF (FormDate) VALUES & valuestring"
DoCmd.RunSQL qs
'CurrentDb.Execute qs  'When I run this I get "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"  Locals window shows (4/1/2016), which is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use Format:

```
ValueString = Format(data1, "(0)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Include spaces before and after the `&` characters:

```vb
ValueString = "'(" & data1 & "')"
```

The problem was because Access interpreted `data1&` to mean a variable named `data1` whose type is Long.

As [LiamH pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037867/entering-parentheses-in-string-values/35038032?noredirect=1#comment57800721_35038032), if you want `ValueString` to contain *(6)* instead of *'(6')*, remove the apostrophes:

```vb
ValueString = "(" & data1 & ")"
```

Comment: Remove the apostrophes to return the desired result. currently this answer gives  `'(6')`